# Is it possible to change visual studio 2008 interface language?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, interface

I've installed a copy of a Spanish version of visual studio 2008 (professional edition) on my computer and I was wondering if there is a possible or if exist some language pack that change this interface to English.

I did some research but I wasn't find anything useful for VS2008 professional.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that I've found is to install a english version of vs 2008 over the spanish version. Only after doing this I was able to change the interface language.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel, i've just found another answer to this issue, look at this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/03/24/560579.aspx

Basically you just have to go to
Tools -> Options -> Enviroment -> International Settings
And look into the combo for the language you want.

I've tryed this and it works for my Visual Studio 2008 ver. 9.0.30729.1 SP.
Hope this is useful to you too.